# Best diets for senior cats (UK)

Tags: cats, diet, senior-pet

I’m new to the forums! I currently own a male 11-13 year old cat (his age is estimated as he is a rescue). We feed him on Purina Gourmet Fancy Feast, I wondered if there were better healthier options in the UK as he’s showing his age. Is his current diet okay or should I upgrade it? Thank you!

Edit: This is a photo of the food we feed him

https://ibb.co/gw456yp
https://ibb.co/y0K8PPk
https://ibb.co/wsZFgf5

Comment: Maybe useful for an answer: Do your cat have any issues, for example kidney or other things diagnosed by a vet?

Comment: What Allerleirauh said, do you have a blood test that shows any deficiencies or other problems?

Comment: No, he does not have any issues that we know of.

Comment: your question will likely be closed as opinion based so i make this a comment. most cats will develop kidney problems when they get old (big as well as small cats)it is mainly caused by the meat proteins that all cats eat,you can delay the onset of kidney failiure by changing the food to a veterinary prescribed diet(ask your vet about this)effective medical treatment is avaliable but veterinary medicine lags 10-20 years behind human medicine so few vets treat kdney failiure in cats and dogs with calcitrol a medication aproved in the early 1980s for human use.

Comment: Oh, I wasn’t aware about this, I will definitely ask a veterinarian about this.